# Calculate offset top of elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to check what offset top 3 elements on my page have while im scrolling? I have 3 sections with IDs `#first, #second, #third`, and I want to calculate what offset they have inside the window while scrolling.

I got those elements by ID like this:

```
$scope.first = angular.element(document.querySelector('#first'));
$scope.second = angular.element(document.querySelector('#second'));
```

But now I dont know how to get check that offset and assign some variables to true/false based on it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `angular.element` for this. `document.querySelector('#first').offsetTop` is what you're looking for. Also you need to add a listener to window `scroll` event if you want to get these values while you scroll:

```
const first = document.querySelector('#first');
const second = document.querySelector('#second');

const scrollListener = () => {
  console.log(first.offsetTop, second.offsetTop)
};
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollListener);

// Don't forget to remove listener
$scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
  window.removeEventListener(scrollListener);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$(window).scrollTop()  is useful for calculate how much the user has scrolled down.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var first = $("#first");
      var winOffset_first = first.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      console.log(winOffset_first)
    });
});
```